# Remove innerHTML from directiveAngular

Tags: angular, directive, angular-directive

I have some directive like this

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appNoValuesFound]'
})
export class NoValuesFoundDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() initValues: any = null;
    @Input() displayText: any = this.translate.instant('NoValuesFound');
    @Input() columns = 3;

    get haveValues(): boolean {
        if (this.initValues) {
            return this.initValues || this.initValues.length > 0;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private translate: TranslateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.haveValues) {
            this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<tr><td colspan="' + this.columns + '">' + this.displayText + '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
```

And html like this

```
<tbody appNoValuesFound [initValues]="values" [displayText]="'Nothing to diplay'" [columns]="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
    values
      </td>
</tbody>
```

Directive will replace innerHtML if values are empty. Only problem is what I have is that if I need to do something with values like pipe, and values are undefined it will show me error in console. I need somehow from directive prevent html render of innerHTML in values are empty, and replace with my innerHTML

Comment: How does that error look like?

Comment: It can be anything, i jut simplifed the question, whta i need is to prevent html render from directive above :)

Comment: Why don't you inject your pipe in your directive? Then if your values are not undefined, transform them in ts file